# mysql sum(column) fetches value of only one row from dynamic table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, sum

I have a dynamic table which has two rows, when I call sum(cr) function in my stored procedure to assign the total sum to a variable, the function returns the value of only one row, here is my code from the stored procedure:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS create_table;
CREATE PROCEDURE create_view(IN `query` TEXT, IN `lock_name` CHAR(64), IN 
`timeout` TINYINT UNSIGNED)
BEGIN

-- output from GET_LOCK()
    DECLARE lock_res TINYINT UNSIGNED;

    -- error in query
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER
        FOR SQLEXCEPTION
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE VALUE '45000' SET
                MESSAGE_TEXT  = '[dyn_lock] Dynamic SQL returned an error';

    -- get lock or exit with err
    SET lock_res = GET_LOCK(`lock_name`, IFNULL(`timeout`, 5));
    IF (lock_res IS NULL) THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE VALUE '45000' SET
                MESSAGE_TEXT  = '[dyn_lock] Could not acquire lock: Unknown error';
    ELSEIF (lock_res = 0) THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE VALUE '45000' SET
                MESSAGE_TEXT  = '[dyn_lock] Could not acquire lock: Timeout expired';
    END IF;

    -- create dynamic view
    SET @dyn_sql = CONCAT('CREATE temporary table `', lock_name, '` AS ', query, ';');
    PREPARE stmt_dyn_view FROM @dyn_sql;
    EXECUTE stmt_dyn_view;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt_dyn_view;

END$$
```

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS post_entries;
CREATE PROCEDURE `post_entries`(IN `query` TEXT, IN `timeout` TINYINT UNSIGNED, 
posting_type varchar(255))
BEGIN

    DECLARE eof int default 0;
    declare accountID integer(11) default 0;
    declare balance float;
    declare total_amount float;

    CALL create_dynamic_table(`query`, 'dyn_table', `timeout`);

    if(posting_type='receivable')then
        set total_amount=0;
        select sum(dr) into total_amount from dyn_view;
    elseif(posting_type='component receivable') then
        set total_amount=0;
        select sum(cr) into total_amount from dyn_view;
    elseif(posting_type="component payable")then
        set total_amount=0;
        select sum(cr) into total_amount from dyn_view;
    end if;
    drop temporary table dyn_view;

END$$
```

There are two values to be summed, 180000 and 90000, but I get only 90000.

Comment: Kindly post code of your whole procedure then only we can help you.

Comment: `SUM()` is an aggregate function that calculates the sum of all or distinct values in an expression. So it is obvious that it returns only one row. Are you trying to sum based on specific column? In  that you have to use `group by`

Comment: there's a -180000  value